# WNR2000 N300 Router Overloaded?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection, dhcp, hotspot

Hope someone can help point me in the right direction. Here is my issue:

For a local fitness club, they offer free open access WiFi. It has a dedicated connection, with a 16/3 broadband connection. The router connected to the broadband modem is a wnr2000v4 Netgear router. The wireless in the router is disabled and throughout the building, there are 3 or 4 Unify Indoor 802.11n APs that are hard wired back to the router. On a typical day, at least 100 wifi connections can be using Wifi while people work out.

There seems to be an issue with some devices not being able to obtain a DHCP address (250 addresses are allotted in the DHCP pool). At least, it appears this way. For example someone's iphone may just have the spinning circle forever when trying to connect. However, some people have no issues connecting at the same time.

Before the netgear, we had a sonicwall tz215 (or similar) and it was all around horrible when it came to devices getting DHCP. The netgear worked flawlessly for a little while (or so it seemed) but more complaints are arising now.

Could it the router is being overloaded causing DHCP issues? Would a PC linux based router help with this issue? I just don't know where to start looking.

As I said earlier, this is a very basic setup: We have a dedicated broadband connection going to the netgear router, which is wired to Unify APs around the building. It seems like devices should connect fine regardless if a lot of bandwidth is being consumed and their browsing experience would just be degraded. What could be the cause of devices not being able to to join an open, no encryption, wireless hotspot? When I check, the DHCP is not maxed out when issues like this occur either.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: This is off topic because it is a commercial application. SU is for home networking issues per the **[help]**. Additionally, it is too broad to answer considering all the possible device types, OS levels, security and connection scenarios. You can reword the question to get it on-topic. That being said, my guess is if you look at those who are complaining, they either need to update their device software or haven't restarted their device in days.

Comment: Not really an answer so I'll just comment that, with 100 clients on 3 AP's that is quite a lot so it may be that the AP's are not responding to the connection request. It is also possible to get stuck sessions which may need to be cleared out from time-to-time, we get that on our CISCO AP's

Comment: Sorry for the improper post, I did not realize it was for home use only. Julian, I am thinking you are right and will start looking at the AP side first and see if its being overwhelmed.

Comment: Most APs especially the home routers wont support more than 30 simultaneous users. You might need to spread out users over two routers, but first decrease DHCP lease time to say 6 hours and see if it makes things any better.

Answer (score 0):

This seems propagation related issues, not bandwidth or server overload issues. I doubt a 16/3 mbit/sec internet connection might overload a consumer grade router those days. If you have a spare pc, it might be worth installing something like pfSense to check out if its a overload issue. But i would bet more on problems on the radio side of things.